# Application lifecycle, setting a timer to logout the user

Tags: android, session, static, android-lifecycle, lifecycle

I'm pretty new to android and currently I ran into a problem concerning login and logout of a user. I have these activities:

- Splash activity
- Map activity
- Transactions activity
- Settings activity

The idea is that when a user goes to transactions a login is requested. After the user is logged in he stays login while he uses the app. Even if he stays on a page and does nothing for multiple minutes. When the app locks or closes the user is logged out after 60 seconds. When he comes back in time he stays logged in, otherwise a new login form is shown.

So I was thinking on how to solve this. My first thoughts were to set a timer when the app locks/is closed. When the user comes back the timer is checked. If after 60 seconds the user details (in memory) are thrown away.

I think it has something to do with the application lifecycle, maybe a static variable. But I don't know where to start.

Has anyone got a solution or a tip so I can finish this thing?? Would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Shared Preference in this case
Note the current time when the app closes and on Restarting the app compare the current time with the stoppage time and then find the difference in time. If it is greater than your demand then Request Login Page.
If you want sample code for difference of time I can edit my Post

Comment: Yeah, that would work. Only thing is I don't know how to make a check when the app is closed. Ondestroy won't work since I have more activities. Do you have an example of this onappclose check?

Comment: Just write your code in the OnStop method and Override it. Note the time stamp in this method and when the app restarts then calculate the  time difference

Comment: But the OnStop will trigger as well if the user goes to another page/activity right?

Comment: "When the app locks or closes the user is logged out after 60 seconds". In this line it is obvious that you should use OnStop in every activity so that if app locks (in any activity) then the timer starts and when app open again then onRestart will work

Comment: Only problem is this: a user goes from transaction to map activity. The timestamp is set. From the map activity he leaves the app. Again the timestamp is set. Then he comes back into the app, lands on the map activity. He then navigates to transactions. Again a timestamp is set from the onstop of the map activity. Here is the problem that transaction will check for the currenttime and timestamp and let the user through. How do you catch this when he comes back? Hope you understand :)

Answer (score 0):

You can save the timestamp while user login and also save the  max session time in shared preference. When the user tries to do transaction again you can check the timestamp with current time and session. if the time difference is greater than session time just ask for login.

Comment: In a simple way, yeah, this will work. Only thing is that a user of the app can stay on the page for multiple minutes (like when he's writing down some transaction numbers). Then when he wants a new transaction he has to stay logged in.

Comment: But, while a user is writing something, he can stay on that page, when a user tries to go somewhere else you can ask him to login again. and can save the current data for further use.

Answer (score 0):

> **Service** Class is the answer to your problem.

Create a background service which starts each time you log in and write the timer code there.

*Reference for creating service:*

https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of a service as well! I tried it out but it stopped right away, so you have to keep it running in some way? And doesn't it keep running if the application closes?

Comment: Service keeps running even if the application closes,that is the whole point.
I think you made a mistake in the implementation, try to follow the google guidelines